# Error CS0669 al decompilar una clase

Tags: c#

Estoy probando un código en C# que lo descompile y obtuve varios errores, donde uno en particular no lo entiendo. El error es el `CS0669 public` y me lo indica en la siguiente linea:

```
public  extern CoCOMServerClass();
```

Clase

```
internal class wrapper
{
    [Guid("52759D4E-12F7-47A5-A7CE-387BFE7CBF38"), TypeLibType(4288)]
    [ComImport]
    public interface IPrnDrvServer2
    {
        [DispId(1)]
        int callFunc(ref string input, out string output);
    }

    [Guid("A15B8FAF-D5D8-4552-BDFC-2F1B6A043E24")]
    [ComImport]

    public class CoCOMServerClass
    {
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
        public  extern CoCOMServerClass();

    }

    private wrapper.IPrnDrvServer2 server = new wrapper.CoCOMServerClass() as wrapper.IPrnDrvServer2;

    public int CallFunc(ref string xmlCommandString, out string xmlCommandResultString)
    {
        return this.server.callFunc(ref xmlCommandString, out xmlCommandResultString);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: decompilaste usando que herramienta ?

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ocupe para descompilar ILSpy

Comment: valida si obtienes el mismo codigo al usar https://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx

Comment: Gracias , probe con ese soft y ya puedo compilar. Al parecer tenia unos metodos puestos en mal orden

Answer (score 0):

El error se debe a que una clase que va a ser importada (tiene el atributo ComImport), no puede tener un constructor definido por el usuario.

O sea que si remueves esa linea, el error deberia salir. Igual, ten en cuenta que muchas de estas cosas estan agregadas por el compilador al pasar del lenguaje que ves, a lenguaje intermedio.

La definición del error esta [aca](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0669)

Tu clase deberia solamente estar definida asi:

```
public class CoCOMServerClass
{
}
```